# How to write SQL query for one-to-one mapping

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have two database tables:

- `db_user`, with column `ID_Veh`;
- `db_vehicles`, with columns `Vehicleid` and `Model`;

Given `db_user.ID_Veh` value, I need to find out `db_vehicles.Model` value, for which `db_user.Vehicleid` equals `db_vehicles.ID_Veh`.

How can I accomplish that using SQL?

Comment: What are you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a [`join`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html), specifically an `inner join` that matches the tables based on the columns containing the vehicle id.

```
select db_vehicles.Model
from db_user 
inner join db_vehicles on db_user.ID_Veh = db_vehicles.Vehicleid
```

Comment: can't this be achieved with minus command in mssql similar must be there in mysql

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee: Minus in MySql is done by an idiom using left join. But minus is not appropriate to this query. Join returns rows in a table AND in another, minus returns rows in a table AND NOT in another.